# Fancybox/Lightbox mouseover effect

Tags: jquery, lightbox, mouseover

I am building a website showcasing my clients photography images. She has asked for a lightbox popup. This I have done using the **Lightbox jQuery plugin** (edited) but now she wants a mouseover effect showing the photo in picture frame. This website http://masteringretouching.com/proof1.php has the required effect but I have no idea how to do it. Can someone please help?

Comment: what exactly is the problem, you desire a mouse over effect inside a fancy box?

Comment: You are not using fancybox in the site of reference.

Comment: @smb - Yes I want to have a mouseover which changes the fancybox image for another image. Here is her previous website which just uses a normal mouseover effect. http://www.asc-photography.com/html/belstone9.html This needs to be in a fancybox/lightbox. I'm not fussy whether I use Fancbox or Lightbox to achieve this effect